# Farming game in C# cant fix level system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a Farming game in Unity and I tried to implement an EXP System. I can not implement a function where you can plant a crop from an X player level.

This Code manages the whole farm

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FarmManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Money Settings")]
    public PlantItem selectPlant;
    public bool isPlanting = false;
    public int money = 100;
    public Text moneyTxt;

    [Header("Button Color Settings")]
    public Color buyColor = Color.green;
    public Color cancelColor = Color.red;
    public Color lockedColor = Color.grey;

    [Header("Button Audio Settings")]
    public AudioSource clickSound;

    [Header("Cursor Settings")]
    public Texture2D cursorArrow;
    public Texture2D cursorPickaxe;

    [Header("XP Settings")]
    public int maxExp;
    public float updatedExp;
    public float plusXp;
    public Image ExpBar;
    public float expIncreasedPerSecond;
    public int playerLevel;
    public Text levelText;
    public Text xpLevel;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.SetCursor(cursorArrow, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.ForceSoftware);
        moneyTxt.text = "$"+money;
        playerLevel =1;
        expIncreasedPerSecond =5f;
        maxExp = 25;
        updatedExp = 0;
        plusXp = 0;
        
    }


    void Update () {
        //updatedExp += expIncreasedPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        
        ExpBar.fillAmount = updatedExp / maxExp;

        levelText.text = playerLevel + "";
        xpLevel.text = updatedExp + "/" + maxExp;

        if (updatedExp >= maxExp)
        {
            plusXp = updatedExp-maxExp;
            playerLevel++;
            updatedExp=0+plusXp;
            maxExp+=maxExp;
        }
    }


    public void SelectPlant(PlantItem newPlant)
    {
        if(selectPlant == newPlant)
        {
            Debug.Log("Deselected" + selectPlant.plant.plantName);
            selectPlant.btnImage.color = buyColor;
            selectPlant.btnTxt.text = "Buy";
            selectPlant = null;
            isPlanting = false;
            clickSound.Play();
            
        }
        else
        {
            if(selectPlant!=null)
            {
                selectPlant.btnImage.color = buyColor;
                selectPlant.btnTxt.text = "Buy";
            }
            
            selectPlant = newPlant;
            selectPlant.btnImage.color = cancelColor;
            selectPlant.btnTxt.text = "Cancel";
            Debug.Log("Selected" + selectPlant.plant.plantName);
            isPlanting = true;
            clickSound.Play();

        }
    }

    public void Transaction(int value)
    {
        money+=value;
        moneyTxt.text = "$"+money;
    }


    public void GiveXP (float value) 
    {
        updatedExp += value;
    }
    
}
```

And this is the code where I import the information from

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Plant", menuName ="Plant")]

public class PlantObject : ScriptableObject
{
    [Header("Plant settings")]
    public string plantName;
    public Sprite[] plantStages;
    public float timeBtwStages;
    [Header("Money Settings")]
    public int buyPrice;
    public int sellPrice;
    [Header("XP Settings")]
    public int xpAmount;
    public int levelNeeded;
    [Header("Plant Icon")]
    public Sprite icon;
}
```

I tried doing it this way, but it would not fix my issue and would not disable the crop until the needed level was reached and it gave me a ton of errors.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FarmManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Money Settings")]
    public PlantItem selectPlant;
    public bool isPlanting = false;
    public int money = 100;
    public Text moneyTxt;

    [Header("Button Color Settings")]
    public Color buyColor = Color.green;
    public Color cancelColor = Color.red;
    public Color lockedColor = Color.grey;

    [Header("Button Audio Settings")]
    public AudioSource clickSound;

    [Header("Cursor Settings")]
    public Texture2D cursorArrow;
    public Texture2D cursorPickaxe;

    [Header("XP Settings")]
    public int maxExp;
    public float updatedExp;
    public float plusXp;
    public Image ExpBar;
    public float expIncreasedPerSecond;
    public int playerLevel;
    public Text levelText;
    public Text xpLevel;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.SetCursor(cursorArrow, Vector2.zero, CursorMode.ForceSoftware);
        moneyTxt.text = "$"+money;
        playerLevel =1;
        expIncreasedPerSecond =5f;
        maxExp = 25;
        updatedExp = 0;
        plusXp = 0;
        
    }


    void Update () {
        //updatedExp += expIncreasedPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        
        ExpBar.fillAmount = updatedExp / maxExp;

        levelText.text = playerLevel + "";
        xpLevel.text = updatedExp + "/" + maxExp;

        if (updatedExp >= maxExp)
        {
            plusXp = updatedExp-maxExp;
            playerLevel++;
            updatedExp=0+plusXp;
            maxExp+=maxExp;
        }
    }


    public void SelectPlant(PlantItem newPlant)
    {
        if(selectPlant == newPlant)
        {
            Debug.Log("Deselected" + selectPlant.plant.plantName);
            selectPlant.btnImage.color = buyColor;
            selectPlant.btnTxt.text = "Buy";
            selectPlant = null;
            isPlanting = false;
            clickSound.Play();
            
        }
        else
        {
            if(selectPlant!=null)
            {
                selectPlant.btnImage.color = buyColor;
                selectPlant.btnTxt.text = "Buy";
            }
            
            selectPlant = newPlant;
            selectPlant.btnImage.color = cancelColor;
            selectPlant.btnTxt.text = "Cancel";
            Debug.Log("Selected" + selectPlant.plant.plantName);
            isPlanting = true;
            clickSound.Play();

        }
        if (selectPlant.plant.levelNeeded > playerLevel)
        {
            selectPlant.btnImage.color = lockedColor;

        }

    }

    public void Transaction(int value)
    {
        money+=value;
        moneyTxt.text = "$"+money;
    }


    public void GiveXP (float value) 
    {
        updatedExp += value;
    }
    
}
```

I have been stuck on this for weeks now any ideas?

Comment: Am I missing something here? Where are you calling the methods you've created? Also, what errors are you getting?

Comment: @Bart This is the error message I get: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
FarmManager.SelectPlant (PlantItem newPlant) (at Assets/Scripts/FarmManager.cs:96)
PlantItem.BuyPlant () (at Assets/Scripts/PlantItem.cs:40)

Comment: @Bart which methods do you mean?